# Find the language generated by the Context Free Grammar

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, derivation

I am trying to find the language generated by this context-free grammar

```
S → aSb | bbY | Yaa
Y → bY | aY | ε
```

I understand that one way to solve is this to find set of strings that satisfies this grammar, But I don't see a common pattern in those strings.

Some of the strings that belong to this language are

```
     aa,bb
     aaa, bbb, bba, baa, 
     abbb, aaab, baaa
```

Comment: Try to find the language generated by $Y$ as the start symbol first.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this is not a very well-defined question. What you're presumably looking form is some closed form *description* of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generation of strings by this context-free grammar can be split into four stages.

At each stage, we can use some expressions to represent all sentential forms that can be generated so far. As long as you can understand/manipulate them consistently, you are good to go.

1. Apply $S \to aSb$ zero or more times.
   We get $S\Rightarrow^*a^kSb^k$ for $k\ge0$.
2. Apply $S\to bbY$ or $S \to Yaa$ once.
   We get $a^kSb^k\Rightarrow a^kbbYb^k$ or $a^kSb^k\Rightarrow a^kYaab^k$.
3. Apply $Y\to bY$ or $Y\to aY$ zero or more times.
   We get $a^kbbYb^k\Rightarrow^*a^kbb(a+b)^*Yb^k$ or $a^kYaab^k\Rightarrow^* a^k(a+b)^*Yaab^k$.
4. Apply $Y\to \varepsilon$.
   We get $a^kbb(a+b)^*b^k$ or $a^k(a+b)^*aab^k$.

In the end we get $a^kbb(a+b)^*b^k + a^k(a+b)^*aab^k$. (This is not a regular expression. I have not defined formally the meaning of such an expression. It is believed that an ordinary reader can interpret it correctly naturally.)

In plain English, a word is generated by this grammar iff its alphabet is $\{a,b\}$ and there exist $k\ge0$ such that it

- starts with $k$ $a$'s and ends $k$ $b$'s and,
- ignoring those $2k$ symbols, either starts with $bb$ or ends with $aa$.